# Wrong results for the HSV conversion?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have this code to convert from RGB to HSV

```
  func rgbToHSV (_ r:Double, _ g:Double, _ b:Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) {

    let cor01 : (Double) -> CGFloat = { valor in
      return CGFloat(valor / 255)
    }

    let corRGB = UIColor(red: cor01(r),
                         green: cor01(g),
                         blue: cor01(b),
                         alpha: 1.0)

    var hue         : CGFloat = CGFloat.infinity
    var saturation  : CGFloat = CGFloat.infinity
    var brightness  : CGFloat = CGFloat.infinity
    var alpha       : CGFloat = CGFloat.infinity

    _ = corRGB.getHue(&hue,
                      saturation:&saturation,
                      brightness:&brightness,
                      alpha:&alpha)

    return (Double(hue), Double(saturation), Double(brightness))
  }
```

I convert RGB = (168, 131, 126) to HSV and get

```
HUE = 0.019841269841269771
SAT = 0.24999999999999994
BRI = 0.6588235294117647
```

I use the online conversion of [this site](http://colorizer.org) and [this site](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html) and both give me a hue of 7 degrees.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the value of `0.01984126984126977` comes as a part of a whole, where the whole is 360 degrees. You can multiply by `360` and get a value of `7.1428571428571175`.

```
let result = rgbToHSV(168, 131, 126)
print(result)
print(result.0 * 360)
```

Output:

```
(0.01984126984126977, 0.24999999999999994, 0.6588235294117647)
7.1428571428571175
```

Comment: ah, that is a problem of crappy documentation as usual with almost all Apple writes. THANKS!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @SpaceDog This has nothing to do with Apple's documentation. Apple clearly documents that the HSV values you get are in the range 0.0 - 1.0. The misunderstanding is that you didn't realize that the websites you linked to show the hue in the range 0 - 360 and the saturation and value in the range 0 - 100. It's no different than the documentation for red, green, and blue being in the range 0.0 - 1.0. There's nothing about those typically being in the 0 - 255 range but you already knew about those ranges. Now you know that HSV uses 360/100/100, not 255/255/255.

Comment: not exactly. If you read the quick help for `getHue` Apple says that `hue` is from 0 to 1 on old versions of iOS and that can have "any value" on newer versions.... any value, for me, is any float number from minus to plus infinity.... and sorry but with the exception of the Swift guide and a couple of other docs, 99.9999% of their documentations are pure crap, that should be burnt in a full moon ceremony at Stone Henge, in the autumn equinox, to please the evil spirits and free the human kind from that shit.